# SQL Server 2008 development and versioning?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a live SQL Server 2008 database and I need to start working on some changes in its structure. Obviously since it is live I want to have a dev copy I work on. How do I keep track of those changes so I can easily update my live DB when the time comes?

Comment: Red Gate's SQL Source Control has done good things for our organization in that way, but I don't know your budget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big tick for Red Gate's SQL Source Control for this: http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/07/rocking-your-sql-source-control-world.html

Plus you can easily tie it into your CI process for automated releases: http://www.troyhunt.com/2011/02/automated-database-releases-with.html

Answer (score 0):

Redgate tool's are excellent.

You can also use a Visual Studio database project to source control and synchronise schema and data, and deploy: [Working with Database Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee70aty.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to script all of you database schema changes in a sql file that you can run against the live database once development is done.

I recommend using IF NOT EXISTS checks so that your script is re-runnable without causing errors.

For Example:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
               WHERE TABLE_NAME='tablename') 
BEGIN
      CREATE TABLE...
END
```

This method will also allow you to script data conversions, if you have some refactoring of your database.

Comment: And while you are scripting the changes, put them in source control with the other code they need to be run with for a version. And use ALTER table if the table has data or you will lose the data.